# How can I apply css3 scale to an element's first-letter pseudo-element?

Tags: html, css, scale

I have a paragraph tag with a first-letter pseudo rule. I would like to apply the scale rule to that first letter but it doesn't seem to work.

Does the first-letter pseudo element support css3 scale?

```
<p>This is some Text</p>
<p>This is some more Text</p>

p:first-child:first-letter { font-family: "Baskerville"; font-size: 60px; -webkit-transform: scaleX(.8); display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Why are there like 3 downvotes on this question? I don't see what's unclear or not useful about it.

Comment: I can not figure that out at all. There's nothing wrong with the question IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nx47x/), you sure you're using Webkit browser to view the results?

[image]

UPDATE:
This DOES work: http://jsfiddle.net/szXHZ/5/

You have to float the element and you have to set display to block!!

You will have to mess around with the style a little because it looks a bit ragedy (change line-height for a better look and maybe remove the clear that i've put on the second paragraph), but the transform does work when hovered. You can alter it so that you don't need to hover if you prefer that..

Comment: I looked at it in Chrome 14 and Safari 5.1 on both Mac and PC... nope, doesn't scale to 0.8.

Comment: @BoltCock, very strange, I uploaded a pic of what I see. Perhaps this is a platform bug? I'm on Ubuntu and it's fine in Chrome, Chromium and FF - all quite recent versions

Comment: ok, I think I see the problem, ignore my answer, you're right, it's not scaling, I have got the wrong idea here

Comment: No it works well. open it jsfiddle.net/sP3JZ/4 Problem is `.8`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
<p><span class="firstletter">T</span>his is some Text</p>

.firstletter { font-family: "Baskerville"; -webkit-transform: scale(2); display: inline-block; }
```

Now it works. http://jsfiddle.net/sP3JZ/7/

Comment: I did not downvote, but I'm not one to take kindly to answers that address "Does X support this?" with "Do Y." That said, you did provide a working alternative which is why I didn't downvote.

Comment: @BoltClock Don't you see "but it doesn't seem to work."? I suggested another working solution to this problem. What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: @stephenmurdoch What's wrong with my answer? It's my working solution. You can apply this rules with the help of simple function on dynamic pages too

Comment: your code, like mine, does not work if you remove the "font-size: 60px" - here's a js fiddle of your code with the font-size removed: http://jsfiddle.net/sP3JZ/ - I think scale only works on hover and hover doesn't appear to work when applied to first-letter

Comment: your code does not apply the transform to the first-letter pseudo element, instead it works on a custom class (called **.firstletter**) that you have created. This won't work on dynamic code, since you can't isolate the first letter without using pseudo elements (or js). So, your code is ok, nothing really wrong with it, but it's not solving the original problem. The question applies specifically to whether or not pseudo elements (:first-letter etc) support scaling as a transform function. You have managed to prove that custom classes do. But we knew that already :)